# can't submit an async task to openfaas

Tags: openfaas

OpenFaas on GKE was working fine until the morning, when I sent load on it. Since then it's been unresponsive to async requests, but sync requests are working fine. How do I get the async tasks to work again?

Comment: It could be the queue manager, have a poke around and see what it's status is

Comment: Can you check the log of `queue-worker` and `nats`? `nats` also doesn't support more than 1mb sized data.